# flexbox: контент overflow-ится при nowrap и выравнивании по центру

Tags: css, flexbox, выравнивание, центрирование

Обычная задача - выровнять 2 блока по центру страницы. Ширина блоков указана в единицах измерения `vw`. Проблема при выравнивании флексом в том, что когда уменьшаешь ширину окна, весь контент уходит в `overflow`. А нужно поведение именно `nowrap`.

Собственно выровнять получилось с помощью `display: table`. Но хотелось бы узнать, можно ли это сделать как-то с `flex` или хотя бы `float`-ами.

Ниже привел codepen, в css 3 варианта (2 закоментировано), которыми пытался решить:

- `display: table`
- `float: left`
- `display: flex`

Также пробовал display: `inline-block`, но получил результат как и с флоатом.

https://codepen.io/tsamsiyu/pen/BYwzEp?editors=1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так?

```css
/* COMMON STYLES */

#left>div,
#right>div {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1vw;
}

#left {
  width: 20vw;
  min-width: 200px;
}

#right {
  flex-basis: 60%
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div style="height: 150px"></div>
    <div style="height: 30px"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div style="height: 50px"></div>
    <div style="height: 50px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Т.е. поведение, которое можно получить с display: table (фиксированная минимальная ширина), здесь недостижимо?

Comment: @DmitryLikhovoi, можно поменять `min-width` на `max-width` у `#left` & `#right`